# To Test Installation of Wolfram Workbench 2 in Eclipse of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: eclipse, mathematica

I want to have this [editor](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/path.html) in Ubuntu 16.04. 
I want to include .m files in my project as functions to keep things organized. 
You can use Eclipse 3.8 or 4.5 to reproduce the problem. 
I downloaded now the official *Workbench_2.0.0_ECLIPSE.zip* in my Wolfram user page. It has the Wolfram Workbench plugins. 
I managed to import it in my system. 
I managed to disable the two software sources below for 3.8 Eclipse, since I am using 4.5.

Still, I cannot start .nb file in my Mathematica Development of Eclipse. I get the same error as in the screenshot below under the section. 
It would be great to understand those plugins which downloaded/installed in Wolfram Premiere service.

How can you test if the Wolfram Workbench .zip file is correctly installed in Eclipse?

---

### Eclipse 3.8 with other sources

I install Eclipse 3.8. 
I follow the instructions in the thread [How to install the Wolfram Workbench plugin into Eclipse Kepler?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/how-to-install-the-wolfram-workbench-plugin-into-eclipse-kepler) and successfully install the sources

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- http://workbench.wolfram.com/update

However, they do not seem to work with Mathematica 10. In Eclipse, I create Basic Mathematica project. Add project where .m and .nb files. The .m open successfully. However, clicking .nb file gives the error

[image]

which suggests me that the sources install the plugins for old Mathematica (7).

### Eclipse 4.5 Mars with other sources

I uninstall Eclipse 3.8, and install the precompiled Eclipse 4.5 of the official site [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) by solving the case together [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280867/16920) about *To Have Eclipse 4.5 in Path?* 
I however get the same error as in 3.8.

How can you have .nb files of Mathematica 10 Workbench in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I think they call this **Wolfram Workbench** and is installed alongside **Eclipse**, which is a Java IDE (Integrated Development Environement).

Comment: I've never done it, but using Google to search for "Install Wolfram Workbench Linux" turned up far better results than my searches for "Install Mathematica Development Editor Linux".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from Wolfram Premier service. 
They provided the prerelease of Wolfram Workbench 3, and recommends to use it in Ubuntu 16.04 instead of Workbench 2. Open .nb file again and you get a similar error

```
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/Mathematica
```

as in the screenshot of the body. 
I think Wolfram Workbench does not support notebook files. 
I think the path should be 10.0 there, but for some reason, they keep there 9.0.