# How to get Eclipse Mars 4.5 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I get Eclipse 3.8 in apt-get, and having a problem with .nb files with it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766993/how-to-have-mathematica-10-workbench-in-ubuntu-16-04) about *How to Have Mathematica 10 Workbench in Ubuntu 16.04?* I do not understand how this can possible that only 3.8 in apt-get, since 3.8 is already two years old.

Comment: You can't. You need to download 4.5 from the website and run the installer.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's just not how things work. If you need a newer version than is in the repositories, you need to find an alternate method to install. In this case, eclipse makes an installer that works great, so there's no problem.

Comment: Please don't create a new question that's essentially the same as the one you just asked. You need to wait for an answer. But if 3.8 doesn't work for you, don't use it. Get 4.5 from the website and run the installer.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it once the question was re-opened or – in the case of a duplicate – answer the linked question. Don't put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Comment: Right answer is this `sudo mv eclipse /usr/local/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/eclipse
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/eclipse
sudo ln -s /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
eclipse` and config your path. See the history which David deleted. I completely disagree his decision. Current only answer adds a dependency risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use third party ppa's is always a risk and cannot be used in all environments. 
Do to get rid of apt-get's eclipse which is old

```
sudo apt-get purge eclipse*
```

Get and extract the official tarball in Eclipse homepage and do

```
sudo mv eclipse /usr/local/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/eclipse
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/eclipse
sudo ln -s /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
eclipse
```

Configure Java PATHs for Eclipse. So install JRE >=7 and Java PATHs correctly in your system for Workbench 3

```
> Configuring your Java Run-time Environment (JRE) or Wolfram Engine installation are still both necessary on Linux. Further, the version of JRE used should be at least version 1.7
```

The .nb problem is caused by false setting of Java path in your system/Mathematica.

Comment: Other than commercial organisations where security is a key feature, what is the need of so much security for a layman?

Answer (score 6):

You can't get it directly from the standard Ubuntu repository, but you can add this PPA that has Eclipse 4.5 through apt:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mmk2410/eclipse-ide-java`

Ref: https://launchpad.net/~mmk2410/+archive/ubuntu/eclipse-ide-java

Comment: I was having the same issue and I am not sure if it is added to the path or not but you can find it under `/opt/eclipse-ide-java` and there only run eclipse, if you want the icon you can do [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/); the guy who created that repo only focussed on downloading eclipse... (something that of course you could have done yourself)

Comment: another thing that I would recommend is to try the [Eclipse Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/mars/R2/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz) (link for the mirrors of Linux x64) it is brand new to me to so I am also giving it a try :)

Comment: This is not a good solution. Adding 3rd party thing not an option. The best answer in the body.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is using *[umake](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make)* Ubuntu Make is a project designed to enable quick and easy setup of common needs for developers on Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-make

$ umake ide eclipse-jee
```

And that's it